# Overwrite field values based on membership in a set

Tags: python, if-statement, pandas, sqlite, case-when

In Pandas Dataframe, if a df['field1'] is a member of a field df2['field2'], then I need to overwrite the values of a third field df[field3] with a specified value.

I've tried using CASE in sqlite3:

```
conn=sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
sql.write_frame(equip,name='equip',con=conn)
sql.write_frame(list1,name='list1',con=conn)
list2=sql.read_frame("SELECT CASE WHEN (a.'Invoice Number' IN (SELECT     b.'Sold On Invoice Number' FROM equip b) THEN a.'Type'='blah' FROM list1 as a END",conn)
```

Here are data samples with an example:

list1
Out[345]: 
     Invoice Number Invoice Type
0           1341262         None
1           1037970         None
2           1037941         None
3           1805305         None
4           3302259         None
5           1037388         None

list2
Out[347]: 
     Sold On Invoice Number
0                   1341250
1                   3302261
2                   1341271
3                   1037388
4                   134127

Since 1037388 is in both lists, list1['Invoice Type'] needs to equal 'Equipment.'

Comment: Please post some sample of your data, what is the meaning of "is a member"? is `df2['field2']` a Python set?

Comment: I posted samples from my two dataframes. Hopefully it helps. I don't know how to post them more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm assuming that your frames actually look like this (also, [here's](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe) how to make dataframes):

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'Invoice Number':[1341262, 10327970, 1037941, 1805305, 3302259, 1037388], 'Invoice Type':[None]*6})
b = pd.DataFrame({'Sold On Invoice Number':[1341250, 3302261, 1341271, 1037388, 134127]})
```

To get the indices where there's overlap, do a [boolean slice](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) using .isin, like this:

```
idxs = a[a['Invoice Number'].isin(b['Sold On Invoice Number'])].index
```

Then assign 'Equipment' to the overlap:

```
 a.loc[idxs, 'Invoice Type'] = 'Equipment'
```

Comment: Thanks! Much better than my solution of parsing out the overlap into a separate df, changing the desired field and appending the two tables back together.